# Returning a list of keys with ModelState errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate, asp.net-mvc-validation

How can I return a list/array of all keys that have an error?

I have tried to do the below, but it says I can't have that sort of expression for some reason.

```
ModelState.ToList(item => item.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var errors = from modelstate in ModelState.AsQueryable().Where(f => f.Value.Errors.Count > 0) select new  {  Title = modelstate.Key  };
```

Answer (score 3):

Count is a method. You need ()s after is. But I'd prefer Any, anyway:

```
from item in ModelState
where item.Value.Errors.Any()
select item.Key
```

Comment: No overload for method 'ToList' takes '1' arguments

Comment: I also just want the keys collection returned not the KeyValuePair collection

Comment: I rewrote your code as LINQ. This is from memory, so I don't guarantee no errors or typos.