# MVC Knockout validation display and

Tags: validation, jquery, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am using knockout for the first time and I am struggling to get my head around a problem.

I have a page with multiple sections and want to be able to edit a section and submit to the controller, then display the saved details.

Each section is a partial view which contains the display information and the form.  They are shown and hidden as required. I have the code working for submitting, but the problem is when the ModelState is not valid.  I need to return to the form with the validation message displayed

How can I display the form again when the server validation fails?  When the validation fails it currently goes back to the display section.

Also I have noticed the validation message does not display.

I am sure this must be a common problem with a simple fix.  I know there are knockout validation tools, but will need to do more complex business logic validation later on and need to get the technique working.

ViewModel:

```
    [Required]
    public DateTime? InterviewDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div data-bind="if: showAdminInterviewDisplay" id="Display">
<div>
    <button data-bind="click: showInterviewForm" id="EditButton">Edit</button>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.Label("Inteview Date") :
    <label data-bind="text: interviewDate"></label>
</div>
</div>
<div data-bind="if: showAdminInterviewForm" id="Form">   
<div>
    @Html.Label("Interview Date")
    <input data-bind="value: interviewDate" id="interviewDatePicker" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InterviewDate)
</div>

<div>
    <button data-bind="click: saveInterviewDate">Submit</button> 
</div>
```

Knockout ViewModel:

```
function InterviewViewModel() {
    //Data
    var self = this;
    var jsonDate = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.InterviewDate));
    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));

    self.interviewDate = ko.observable(dateFormat(date, "dd/mm/yyyy"));        
    self.showAdminInterviewDisplay = ko.observable(true);
    self.showAdminInterviewForm = ko.observable();

    self.showInterviewForm = function () {
        self.showAdminInterviewDisplay(false);
        self.showAdminInterviewForm(true);
        $("#interviewDatePicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
    };

    //Operations
    self.saveInterviewDate = function() {
        $.ajax("@Url.Action("SaveInterview")", {
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                self.showAdminInterviewDisplay(true);
                self.showAdminInterviewForm(false);
            }
        });
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new InterviewViewModel());
```

Controller:

```
      public ActionResult SaveInterview(KnockoutViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(model);
        }
        return PartialView("_AdminInterview", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a Partial View from your Action Method, return a serialised error model to the success function in the AJAX call.  The error  model will contain all the errors in the ModelState.

See this post on how to get and consume the errors from Model State:
[ASP.NET MVC How to convert ModelState errors to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845852/asp-net-mvc-how-to-convert-modelstate-errors-to-json) (JK's answer)

So you would have something like:

Error Model:

```
public class JsonErrorModel
{
    public JsonErrorModel()
    {
        HasFailed = true;
    }

    public bool HasFailed { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable ErrorList { get; set; } 
}
```

Controller:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{    
  //Do whatever here 
  return Json(new { model });
}

return Json(new JsonErrorModel {ErrorList = ModelState.Errors()});
```

Success function of AJAX call:

```
 success: function (result) {                    
               if(result.HasFailed) {
                   self.showAdminInterviewDisplay(false);
                   self.showAdminInterviewForm(true);
                   DisplayErrors(result.ErrorList);
               }
               else {
                   self.showAdminInterviewDisplay(true);
                   self.showAdminInterviewForm(false);
               }
           }
```

So now, if the server side validation failed, the view will show the form and the validation errors.