# Convert ModelState to JSON for Logging

Tags: c#, json, validation, asp.net-core, logging

How do I convert `ModelState` to JSON in the same format that ASP.NET Core does?

I know I can do [`BadRequest(ModelState)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853011/185123) and it will return JSON to the client.  How does it convert `ModelState` to JSON?  And more importantly, **how can I use what it is using**?

My goal is to log the `ModelState` as JSON in our log "files".

i.e. `var blah = ModelState.ToJson()`

Comment: JSON.NET is built-in. It's what ASP.NET Core uses to serialize objects for responses, so you can simply do the same thing: `JsonCovert.SerializeObject(ModelState)`

Comment: Hi @ChrisPratt - that serializes the whole object.  ASP.NET returns a cleaner version: `{
    "Name": [
        "The Name field is required."
    ] }`

Comment: Use `ModelState.Errors` then.

Comment: FYI, there is no `ModelState.Errors`.  Apparently, each dictionary entry has an `Errors` property though.  Either way that outputs too much info.  `SerializableError` provides what I'm looking for though!  @ChrisPratt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How does it convert ModelState to JSON?

The [`SerializableError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.serializableerror) Class provides this functionality.

> And more importantly, how can I use what it is using?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//get key(s) and error message(s) from the ModelState
var serializableModelState = new SerializableError(ModelState);

//convert to a string
var modelStateJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializableModelState);

//log it
logger.LogInformation("Bad Model State", modelStateJson);
```

**Sample output**

```
{
    "Name": ["The Name field is required."]
}
```

---

I was able to figure this out by digging through the [ASP.NET Core MVC source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Mvc).  The interesting part of [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/3e47fa7c693447f7ad6c0ef7620ee81c12b730f5/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/SerializableError.cs#L43) from the `SerializableError` class:

```
foreach (var keyModelStatePair in modelState)
{
    var key = keyModelStatePair.Key;
    var errors = keyModelStatePair.Value.Errors;
    if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
    {
        var errorMessages = errors.Select(error =>
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage) ?
                Resources.SerializableError_DefaultError : error.ErrorMessage;
        }).ToArray();

        Add(key, errorMessages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to get a list of the error messages for each Model Property that failed validation in the manner you want as indicated above using an extension method. i.e `ModelState.ToJson()`, you need create a **static** class with a static function `ToJson(...)`. The code example will look something like this.

```
public static class ModelStateExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads all the error messages in a <see cref="ModelStateDictionary"/> as 
    /// a collection and returns a JSON <see cref="string"/> of the list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelstate">Current modelstate assuming that you've checked
    /// and confirmed that is Invalid using <see 
    /// cref="ModelStateDictionary.IsValid"/>
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Collection of validation errors for the model as a JSON string.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ToJson(this ModelStateDictionary modelstate)
    {
        List<string> errors = modelstate.Values
                                        .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)
                                        .ToList();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors);
    }
}
```

The `ModelState` property on every controller is normally a `ModelStateDictionary`, so if we want an additional method for it, that is the class we need to extend. You can learn more about extension methods in C# by following this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Let now see how to use our extension method in a sample controller action:

```
public IActionResult Create(UserViewModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string json = ModelState.ToJson();

        // insert code to log json to file here

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```